# Exclude a date for Albedo calculation

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, filter, date

I work on a university project and I use Google engines.
I want to get albedo above a city environment, one value is weird according to other data and I wish to exclude one date corresponding to this value. it 03 may 2020
I have the following code :

```
//Selection de la zone d'intéret
var coordinates = [
  [1.4476356909201105,43.56815240043846],
  [1.4629135534689384,43.57835054290461],
  [1.489692728273625,43.570515538383745],
  [1.4957008764669837,43.580215869922334],
  [1.4637718603537002,43.645217470229156],
  [1.4206848547384656,43.651924914945845],
  [1.405750314943548,43.62260538088805],
  [1.3975105688497975,43.622729646383],
  [1.3981972143576082,43.64434793181369],
  [1.3737500108488285,43.67221848091198],
  [1.3509190477140611,43.664395700454996],
  [1.351434031844919,43.6451448372468],
  [1.389311244078336,43.61081312869245],
  [1.3759216566759913,43.60807868663909],
  [1.3475975294787257,43.636908364039996],
  [1.3424476881701333,43.623240843951535],
  [1.322878291197475,43.626347371429844],
  [1.283687124217135,43.59577215900393],
  [1.3130412196761208,43.581722237846634],
  [1.320250997508152,43.571773408211776],
  [1.3578448390608855,43.55099992930839],
  [1.4102539320666172,43.53706400266811],
  [1.4330848952013862,43.556847081759706],
  [1.4476356909201105,43.56815240043846]];
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coordinates);


// Sélectionner la collection d'images LANDSAT
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate('2013-03-18', '2023-05-06')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 5))
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-05-03').not());

    
// Définir une fonction pour calculer l'albédo
var computeAlbedo = function(image) {
  // Calculer la réflectance TOA (Top Of Atmosphere) de chaque bande
  var toa = image.divide(10000);
  
  // Calculer l'albédo à partir de la réflectance TOA
  var albedo = toa.select(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'])
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
      .multiply(0.356)
      .subtract(0.143);
  
  // Ajouter la date de l'image à la propriété 'system:time_start'
  return albedo.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
};


// Appliquer la fonction computeAlbedo à chaque image de la collection
var albedoCollection = collection.map(computeAlbedo);

// Créer un graphique de l'albédo sur l'année
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: albedoCollection,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
}).setOptions({
  title: 'Albedo au cours du temps',
  vAxis: {title: 'Albedo'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'dd-MM-YYYY'},
});

// Calculer la moyenne de l'albédo sur la période d'un an
var meanAlbedo = albedoCollection.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
});

// Afficher le graphique dans l'interface utilisateur
print(chart);

// Afficher la valeur moyenne de l'albédo
print('Moyenne de l\'albédo :', meanAlbedo);


//incertitude

// Calculer l'incertitude sur la valeur de l'albédo
var albedoStdDev = albedoCollection.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev()).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
});

// Afficher l'incertitude sur la valeur de l'albédo
print('Incertitude sur l\'albédo', albedoStdDev);
```

So far I manage to get my graphic but without excluding the one date I do not want.
So my question is : how can I exclude a date from my filter ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this instead:

```
ee.Filter.date('2020-05-03', '2020-05-04').not()
```

On the end date from the docs:

> The end date (exclusive). Optional. If not specified, a 1-millisecond
> range starting at 'start' is created.